# how to start countdown timer from another countdown timer in android studio

Tags: android

I'm new in android programming. I'd like to ask - how can i start countdown timer from another countdown timer?

I'd like to choose time from second class and to save that time. After, when I choose time from the first class, the chosen time from the second class to start counting together with the choosen time from the first class.

Please help me. Thank you.

Here is the code I have now.

This code is from first class

```
public void rbClick(View view) {

    final boolean check = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

    int selectedTime = 0;


    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.radioButton5min:
            if (check) {

                selectedTime = 300;

                stopTimer();
            }
            break;

        case R.id.radioButton10min:

            if (check) {

                selectedTime = 600;

                stopTimer();
            }
            break;


        case R.id.radioButton15min:

            if (check) {

                selectedTime = 900;

                stopTimer();
            }
            break;

        case R.id.radioButton20min:

            if (check) {
                selectedTime = 1200;

                stopTimer();

            }
            break;


        case R.id.radioButton30min:

            if (check) {


                selectedTime = 1800;

                stopTimer();

            }
            break;


        case R.id.radioButton45min:

            if (check) {

                selectedTime = 2700;

                stopTimer();
            }
            break;


        case R.id.radioButton60min:

            if (check) {

                selectedTime = 3600;

                stopTimer();
            }
            break;

        case R.id.radioButton90min:

            if (check) {

                selectedTime = 5400;

                stopTimer();
            }
            break;


        case R.id.radioButton2H:

            if (check) {

                selectedTime = 7200;

                stopTimer();

            }
            break;


        case R.id.radioButton4H:

            if (check) {

                selectedTime = 14400;

                stopTimer();
            }
            break;


        case R.id.radioButton8H:

            if (check) {

                selectedTime = 28800;

                stopTimer();
            }
            break;


    }


    countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(selectedTime * 1000, 1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
             seconds = millisUntilFinished;


            textView.setText(String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(seconds),
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(seconds) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes
                            (TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(seconds)), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(seconds)
                            - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(seconds))));


        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {

            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
            calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            Intent intent = new Intent(SetTime.this, AlertReciver.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(SetTime.this, 1, intent, 0);

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {

                alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
            }

            countDownTimer = null;
        }

    }.start();


    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {


            Intent intent = new Intent(SetTime.this, ParkingScreen.class);
            Bundle timeTransfer = new Bundle();
            String myAddress = gpsAddress.getText().toString();
            intent.putExtra("myAddress", myAddress);
            timeTransfer.putLong("myTime",seconds);
            intent.putExtras(timeTransfer);
            intent.putExtra("date", date);
            intent.putExtra("time", tvTime.getText().toString());
            intent.putExtra("date", textViewDate.getText().toString());
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }, 200);
}

public void stopTimer() {

    if (countDownTimer != null) {

        countDownTimer.cancel();
    }
}
```

This code is from the second class

```
public void cbRemindertime(View view) {

    boolean check = ((CheckBox) view).isChecked();
    int counter = 0;
    switch (view.getId()) {

        case R.id.cb2min:

            if (check) {

                counter = 120;


            }
            break;

        case R.id.cb3min:

            if (check) {

                counter = 180;
            }
            break;

        case R.id.cb5min:
            if (check) {

                counter = 300;
            }
            break;

        case R.id.cb10min:

            if (check) {

                counter = 600;
            }
            break;
        case R.id.cb15min:

            if (check) {

                counter = 9000;
            }
            break;
        case R.id.cb20min:

            if (check) {

                counter = 1200;
            }
            break;

        case R.id.cb30min:

            if (check) {

                counter = 1800;
            }
            break;


    }


    countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(counter * 1000, 1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

            time = millisUntilFinished;
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {

            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
            calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            Intent intent = new Intent(ReminderTimes.this, AlertReciver.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ReminderTimes.this, 1, intent, 0);

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {

                alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
            }


        }


    };




}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you gave some output of what the code is currently doing. That's a ton of code to try to read and figure out myself. :)

Comment: Please [edit] your question. Don't add code as images

Comment: I want to start two countdown timers at the same time. What I mean by this is, I want to start a second countdown timer when the first timer starts. Example: On the second timer I choose 3 minutes, and on the first timer I choose 30 minutes. So, when I chose 30 minutes from the first timer, I want to start the second countdown timer

Comment: See my previous comment. What happens when you execute the code that you already have? From there I can better figure out what you need to change in your code.